# Convert Unicode to Dictionary

Tags: python, unicode

Version: Python 2.7.10.

I have the following:

```
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers = headers, data = data)
print(r.text)
print(type(r.text))
print(r.text[2])
```

The output

```
{"type":"quote","symbol":"SPY","bid":266.52,"bidsz":5,"bidexch":"P","biddate":"1513040398000","ask":266.55,"asksz":100,"askexch":"P","askdate":"1513040399000"}
{"type":"trade","symbol":"SPY","exch":"P","price":"266.31","size":"0","cvol":"83077533","date":"1513040400000","last":"266.31"}
{"type":"summary","symbol":"SPY","open":"265.58","high":"266.38","low":"265.4793","prevClose":"265.51","close":"266.31"}  
<type 'unicode'>
b
```

I would like to get the output "SPY".

I added the following:

```
new = simplejson.loads(r.text)
print(new)
```

Now, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 63, in <module>
    new = simplejson.loads(r.text)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", 
line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", 
line 373, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end, len(s))
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 160 - 
line 1 column 407 (char 159 - 406)
```

I changed:

```
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers = headers, data = 
data).json()
```

Now, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 51, in <module>
    r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers = headers, data = 
data).json()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 
884, in json
    self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", 
line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", 
line 373, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end, len(s))
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 160 - 
line 1 column 407 (char 159 - 406)
```

I added:

```
new = json.dumps(r.text)
print(new)
print(type(new))
```

Now, output is:

```
"{\"type\":\"quote\",\"symbol\":\"SPY\",\"bid\":266.52,\"bidsz\":5,\"bidexch\":\"P\",\"biddate\":\"1513040398000\",\"ask\":266.55,\"asksz\":100,\"askexch\":\"P\",\"askdate\":\"1513040399000\"}
{\"type\":\"trade\",\"symbol\":\"SPY\",\"exch\":\"P\",\"price\":\"266.31\",\"size\":\"0\",\"cvol\":\"83077533\",\"date\":\"1513040400000\",\"last\":\"266.31\"}
{\"type\":\"summary\",\"symbol\":\"SPY\",\"open\":\"265.58\",\"high\":\"266.38\",\"low\":\"265.4793\",\"prevClose\":\"265.51\",\"close\":\"266.31\"}"

<type 'str'>
```

If I do:

```
for line in r.text.splitlines():
    d = json.loads(line)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example.py", line 54, in <module>
d = json.loads(line)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in 
loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 158 - line 1 column 404 
(char 157 - 403)
```

So I tried:

```
for line in r.text.splitlines():
    print(line)
    print("\n\n")
```

And I got:

```
{"type":"quote","symbol":"SPY","bid":267.18,"bidsz":1,"bidexch":"P","biddate":"1513213200000","ask":267.22,"asksz":3,"askexch":"P","askdate":"1513213200000"}
{"type":"quote","symbol":"SPY","bid":267.18,"bidsz":1,"bidexch":"P","biddate":"1513213200000","ask":267.22,"asksz":3,"askexch":"P","askdate":"1513213200000"}
```

So even though there should be two lines, it interprets everything as a single line.

How can I convert r.text to a dictionary?

Comment: Try using `json.loads`

Comment: Are you using [the requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)? If so, it provides a `.json()` method. But why are you using Python 2?

Comment: Why would `r.text[2]` return "b" in your example?

Comment: I guess server is not providing correct/well-formed json data. Note that the _pasta_ (in your sample) does not have the ending double quote.

Comment: mshsayem - that was a typo on my end, sorry.

Comment: ultimater - for the same reason that r.text[3] returns "r".

Comment: Ah, you mean `r.text[2] would return "b".` is the current behavior IF you did `print(r.text[2])` instead. You should really swap your sentences around, or place that `r.text[2]` remark in the comment of the code.

Comment: `simplejson` sounds like you are using a reeeeally old Python version. Could you please [edit] your question to update it with the Python version information?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using this [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
r.json()
```

Comment: @Everett if you presented the output that you get, then everything should be fine. Probably you get error, and you should check for `r.status_code`, for not 2xx status response.

Comment: r.json() gives simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 160 - 
line 1 column 407 (char 159 - 406).

Comment: @Everett i saw that in your updated question. Check comment above.

Comment: r.status_code is 200. What do you mean when you say "everything is fine"? Are you saying r.text["dinner"] will return "pasta"?

Comment: I am saying that you getting string object in response. r.text is a string. And if response is valid json, then it needs `r.json()` should return dict.

Comment: However, I cannot reach that point, since the line requests.post().json() ... returns an error in the first place, right? requests.post followed by print(r.json()["type"]) throws the same error too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are receiving is [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) format.  Each line of the response is a single json string.   I simulated the response:

```
import json

class r: pass
r.text = u'''\
{"type":"quote","symbol":"SPY","bid":266.52,"bidsz":5,"bidexch":"P","biddate":"1513040398000","ask":266.55,"asksz":100,"askexch":"P","askdate":"1513040399000"}
{"type":"trade","symbol":"SPY","exch":"P","price":"266.31","size":"0","cvol":"83077533","date":"1513040400000","last":"266.31"}
{"type":"summary","symbol":"SPY","open":"265.58","high":"266.38","low":"265.4793","prevClose":"265.51","close":"266.31"}
'''    

print(r.text)
print(type(r.text))
print(r.text[2])

# Parse JSON a line at a time:
for line in r.text.splitlines():
    d = json.loads(line)
    print d['symbol']
```

Output:

```
{"type":"quote","symbol":"SPY","bid":266.52,"bidsz":5,"bidexch":"P","biddate":"1513040398000","ask":266.55,"asksz":100,"askexch":"P","askdate":"1513040399000"}
{"type":"trade","symbol":"SPY","exch":"P","price":"266.31","size":"0","cvol":"83077533","date":"1513040400000","last":"266.31"}
{"type":"summary","symbol":"SPY","open":"265.58","high":"266.38","low":"265.4793","prevClose":"265.51","close":"266.31"}

<type 'unicode'>
t
SPY
SPY
SPY
```

Comment: The actual response is much longer - 3000-4000 characters. I just pasted a representative portion of it above. The entire structure of the response is exactly the same as what I have posted.

Comment: @Everett but as you can see, the representative portion you posted doesn't reproduce the problem. The error is at offset 160.

Comment: ^Updated post accordingly.

Comment: @Everett After your update, is the data *exactly* as shown or have you added newlines to format it for display?  I suspect each individual *line* is a separately json-formatted record (called [json lines format](http://jsonlines.org/)).  The json module itself can only process one complete json entry at a time, hence the "extra data" error, but if those extra newlines are in the data you won't be able to iterate over lines and process the json individually.

Comment: I added the newlines myself to format it for display. The actual data has no space between the first line and the second line - so there would be no space after the comma and it would be:                              ... 5,"bidexch" ...

Comment: @Everett I Updated my answer to what I think the data really is.  Please be precise when providing the data.

Comment: Yes, your "Output" above is correct. However, print(r.text[0]["bid"] throws a TypeError: string indices must be integers. I would like to obtain the value 266.52.

Comment: @Everett, `r.text` is  a string. `r.text[0]` is a single character string.  You have to `json.loads()` the string to convert it to a dictionary before doing lookups.  In my code above, use `d['bid']` to reference the value.

Comment: I tried what you have, but I get a "ValueError( ... "extra data" ...". I have shown the error I get in my post above.